# Rotate individual page using itextsharp - MVC C#

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, rotation, itext

i have a Generate PDF fuction, Where i am loading 3 different HTMLS as one pdf.
But i need a page which contains word "Page B" should roate to landscape..because it has some heavy GRID.

```
    public void HTMLToPdfTEST(string[] HTML, string fileName, string folderPath, string physicalApplPath, string requestNumber = "")
    {
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter pdfwriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(physicalApplPath + folderPath + "\\" + fileName + ".pdf", FileMode.Create));

        TableHeader tevent = new TableHeader();
        tevent.Header = requestNumber;
        pdfwriter.PageEvent = tevent;
        document.Open();
        iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet styles = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet();
        iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker hw = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker(document);


        foreach (string htmlPage in HTML)
        {
            if (requestNumber.Contains("Page B")){
                //do page rotation
                hw.Parse(new StringReader(htmlPage));
            }
            else{
                hw.Parse(new StringReader(htmlPage));
            }

            document.NewPage();
        }
        document.Close();
    }
```

Comment: You are using the long deprecated `HTMLWorker`, while you should be using `XMLWorker`.

Answer (score 0):

Got some solution.

```
//added below line and mentioned it in if condition.    
document.SetPageSize(PageSize.A4);
    document.Open();

 foreach (string htmlPage in HTML)
        {

            if (requestNumber.Contains("CMC") && HTML[1] != null)
            {
                //do page rotation
                document.SetPageSize(PageSize.A4.Rotate());
                hw.Parse(new StringReader(htmlPage));
            }
            else
            {
                hw.Parse(new StringReader(htmlPage));
            }

            document.NewPage();
        }
        document.Close();
```

It's working now!!